# Offline Repo issue in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt-mirror

I'm trying to configure Local repository for a closed environment. (LAN network without internet access).

I followed this tutorial in order to configure:

https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-local-apt-repository-server-ubuntu/
But soon enough i realized that the servers in the list are not the one i need.

My Mirror.list file looks like this:
**bold**############# config ##################

## Default variables are good enough.

set base_path /var/www/html/ubuntu

## set mirror_path $base_path/mirror

## set skel_path $base_path/skel

## set var_path $base_path/var

## set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh

## set defaultarch

## set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh

## Set $run_postmirror 0

set  nthreads      20
set  _tilde  0

############# end config ##############

#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe \

## multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted \

and after running again the apt-mirror command, i can see that the file are being download.

On the client side, i changed the settings in the file sources.list to point to the server i configured.

When i save the settings and run the command: sudo apt update (from the client) i'm getting this error:
E: Failed to fetch http://192.168.245.164/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.245.164 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

## I checked:

- communications between the 2 ubuntu machines are solid.
- The firewall is disabled.
- The Apache is running and enabled.
  I have pings from the server, to the client.
  I spent almost a day to figure this out, why am i getting this error.

your help will be grateful.

Comment: All the large and bold text make this hard to read.

Comment: please edit so that the code things look like code, this is very hard to follow. Is the tl;dr that you set up a local mirror and the client machines can't use it? If so, please show the exact contents of the client sources.list and the file structure of the mirror. It looks like they don't match.

Comment: I'll do a new post and stat from the beginning...